# HDFS group Permissions issue, Cluster integrated with Kerberos + AD

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

CDH cluster is integrated with Kerberos + AD.

`user_A` is added to groups `groupX` and `AD_GROUP_X`

`user_B` is added to groups `groupX` and `AD_GROUP_X`

There are two files in HDFS with different group permissions:

`/user/file_a`

- Owner: `user_A`, Group: `groupA`
- Permissions: `u=rwx, g=rwx, o=---`

`/user/file_b`

- Owner: `user_B`, Group: `AD_GROUP_X`
- Permissions: `u=rwx, g=rwx, o=---`

Scenario #1:
`user_A wants to access file /user/file_b ==> Success`

Scenario #2:
`user_B wants to access file /user/file_a ==> failed` expected is `success`

Once AD is integrated with cluster, HDFS reads only AD groups or it can read both AD groups and unix groups.

Comment: Use command `hdfs groups` to check which group(s) your user belongs to, on Hadoop side.

Comment: Only AD group is listed

Comment: How can I configure cluster to read both AD group and Linux groups??

Comment: There are user/groups defined on your Linux edge node, and user/groups defined on the HDFS NameNode. AFAIK you cannot reflect automatically the edge node security config into HDFS security config, that would be a **major security breach**... your best chance is to define ACLs on each directory that you want to share (w/ heritage enabled) so that specific users/groups are granted access.

Comment: Cf. documentation at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html -- but beware of the infamous bug about "umask" side effects on ACLs https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962

Comment: Am trying to read both UNIX groups and AD groups at the same time. Solved it by setting hadoop.security.groups.mapping value to org.apache.hadoop.security.CompositeGroupsMapping

Comment: Will post the complete answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure and combine multiple existing mapping providers without expecting all the users at a single place. i.e AD User can use `LdapGroupMapping` provider for group. Unix user can use the default provider `ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping` for unix group mapping.

It can be configured as shown below.

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.CompositeGroupsMapping</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.providers</name>
    <value>unix,ad01,ad02</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.providers.combined</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>true or false to indicate whether groups from the providers are combined or not. If true, all the providers are tried and the final result is all the groups where the user exists. If false, the first group in which the user was found is returned. Default value is true.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.unix</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad01</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.LdapGroupsMapping</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad02</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.LdapGroupsMapping</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad01.ldap.url</name>
    <value>ldap://</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad02.ldap.url</name>
    <value>ldap://</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad01.ldap.bind.user</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad02.ldap.bind.user</name>
    <value></value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad01.ldap.base</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.security.group.mapping.provider.ad02.ldap.base</name>
    <value></value>
</property>
```

[Support multiple group providers - JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8943)